# Choreographer﹕ Skipped 61 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to load the data from three .svc dot net web services using AsyncTsk for SwipeRefreshLayout . But SwipeRefreshLayout show all the time and only two services immediately working and finish and another third service taking too much time(25 to 30 minutes) for loading the data from server.Can someone suggest me to how to fast working on SwipeRefreshLayout.

Here my SwipeRefreshLayout code

```
swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                //Refreshing data on server
                GetDataTask asyncTask2 = new GetDataTask();
                asyncTask2.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            }
        });
```

And here is AsyncTask code

```
private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            GetAllActivityList();
            Get_InspectorUserList();
            GetAll_FollowUpSettings();
            Loaddata();
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            populateList();

            if (swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }

        }
    }
```

Thanks in advanced .